# How do I position a html table at the very top of the screen?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Using html and css for IE7,  how do I position a html table at the very top of the screen without the top border that is automatically generated?

I am developing in vs2008.

Comment: "without the top border that is automatically generated?"

uh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably seeing the default margins of the document body. 
Set the margin to 0 on the body, preferably using css.
I recommend using a reset css to set the default style for your pages in every browser, there are penty on the net. Sample:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Setting margin, padding, border, and vertical-align of body to 0 individually and together did not remove the border on top.

Comment: Ok, found it. A Div containing the table had padding set. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border on your table.

CSS approach:

```
table / #id-of-your-table / .class-of-your-table { border: 0; }
```

Inline style approach:

```
<table style="border: 0;"> ... </table>
```